# Why clicking select Python interpreter in vscode with no response?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

0. I have already installed python and python extension
1. first I click select python interpreter at the left bottom of the first picture
2. then I choose python.exe in virtual environment of anaconda, but nothing happens.

   [first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph7M3.png)
   [after I click the select python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhbHK.png)
   [choose python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaujh.png)

Comment: maybe selecting interpreted doesn't run it. Maybe after selecting interpreter you have to run it using `Ctrl+F5` (to run in normal mode) or `F5` (to run in debug mode)

Comment: What's response do you want? The python interpreter has been shown at the bottom left 
in the VSCode after you selected the python interpreter?

Comment: the response i want is that the python interpreter is shown at the bottom left, but it didn't . Furthermore when i click F5 it shows that the path for python is not valid, though it should be valid cause i can directly find python.exe under that path

Answer (score 0):

`selecting interpreter` doesn't run it. It only assigns interpreter to current code.

You have to run it using `Ctrl+F5` (to run in normal mode) or `F5` (to run in debug mode).

See it in menu `Run`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now conda environment is available. But problem still exists when i try to just use the python interpreter downloaded from the python website. To be specific, after choosing the python.exe as the interpreter, and try to run the program ,it shows that the python path is not valid

Comment: is this selecting `C:\full\path\to\python.exe` ? OR maybe it has some spaces in path which can make problem.

Comment: is, i selected C:\full\path\to\python.exe, and there is no space in that path, but it still can't work az.

Comment: Did you press `Ctrl+F5` to run it?

Comment: Is, i did, but the extension send notification that there is no python interpreter available

Comment: Anyway, since now i can using conda environment in vscode, it doesn't matter whether or not i can use the interpreter.  Thanks for your help!